# Restricting arguments to certain defined constants

Tags: java

Consider the following code

```
public class ColorScheme {

    public static final int     DARK_BLACK  = 0,
                                WHITE       = 1;

    private int Scheme;

    public ColorScheme() {
        this.Scheme     =   DARK_BLACK;
    }

    public ColorScheme(int SchemeType) {
        this.Scheme     =   SchemeType;
    }
}
```

I want the argument to the constructor  `ColorScheme(int SchemeType)` to be restricted to one of the `static final int` - `DARK_BLACK` or `WHITE` or other constant I may define.

For Ex: When someone instantiates the `ColorScheme` class, he can use

```
 ColorScheme CS  = new ColorScheme(DARK_BLACK);
```

while

```
 ColorScheme CS  = new ColorScheme(5); //or any other non-defined constant
```

should return an error.

Comment: Is there a reason you want an `int`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos No, the answers provided, ie `enum` work beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum is the way to go:

```
public class ColorScheme {

    public enum Color {DARK_BLACK,
                       WHITE}

    private Color Scheme;

    public ColorScheme() {
        this.Scheme     =   Color.DARK_BLACK;
    }

    public ColorScheme(Color SchemeType) {
        this.Scheme     =   SchemeType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for Java [enums](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could consider to use Enum http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

As Mat and Kent have already pointed out: enum's the way to go.

Enums are quite powerful, since they offer many concepts you have with classes, e.g. methods and constructors. The corresponding chapters in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) from Josh Bloch, the author of enums, is definitely worth a read, since they describe the many advantages, the disadvantages, as well as several use cases, e.g. EnumMaps and EnumSets.